# A zeta function for the Klein Four group?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $G$ be a finite group, $S \subset G$ a generating set, $|g|:=|g|_S=$ word-length with respect to $S$. Let $\phi(g,h)=|g|+|h|-|gh| \ge 0$ be the "defect-function" of $S$. The set $\mathbb{Z}\times G$ builds a group for the following operation:

$$(a,g) \oplus (b,h) = (a+b+\phi(g,h),gh)$$

On $\mathbb{N}\times G$ is the "norm": $|(a,g)| := |a|+|g|$ additive, which means that $|a \oplus b| = |a|+|b|$. Define the multiplication with $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$ to be:

$$ n \cdot a := a \oplus a \oplus \cdots \oplus a$$

(if $n=0$ then $n \cdot a := (0,1) \in \mathbb{Z} \times G$).

A word $w := w_{n-1} w_{n-2} \cdots w_0$ is mapped to an element of $\mathbb{Z} \times G$ as follows:

$$\zeta(w) := \oplus_{i=0}^{n-1} (m^i \cdot (0,w_i))$$

where $m := \min_{g,h\in G, \phi(g,h) \neq 0} \phi(g,h)$.

We let $|w|:=|\zeta(w)|$ and $w_1 \oplus w_2:=\zeta(w_1)\oplus \zeta(w_2)$

Then we have $|w_1 \oplus w_2| = |w_1|+|w_2|$.

For instance for the Klein four group $\{0,a,b,c=a+b\}$ generated by $S:=\{a,b\}$, we get sorting the words $w$ by their word-length:

$$0,a,b,c,a0,aa,ab,ac,b0,ba,bb,bc,c0,ca,cb,cc,a00,a0a,a0b,a0c$$

corresponding to the following $\mathbb{Z}\times K_4$ elements $\zeta(w)$:

$$(0,0),(0,a),(0,b),(0,c),(2,0),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c),(2,0),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c),(4,0),(4,a),(4,b),(4,c),(4,0),(4,a),(4,b),(4,c)$$

corresponding to the the following "norms" of words $|w| = |\zeta(w)|$:

$$0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6$$

Let $a_n, n\ge 0$ be the sequence of numbers generated by the Klein four group.

1) Is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n^s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n^s} = \zeta(s-1) + \zeta(s)$$
where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function?

I have checked this with SAGE math up to a certain degree and it seems plausible, however I have no idea how to prove it.

2) Is every $a_n$ the product of primes $p=a_k$ for some $k\le n$?

3) Let $\pi_{K_4}(n) = |\{ k : \text{$a_k$ is prime, $k \le n$}\}|$ be the prime counting function of the sequence.  What is the approximate relationship to the usual prime counting function $\pi(n)$?

Comment: What is your definition of $a_n$?

Comment: @ThomasBrowning It is the sequence for the Klein group defined in the previous question.

Comment: I don't see an integer sequence defined in the previous question

Comment: @ThomasBrowning https://mathoverflow.net/a/351113/6671 sorry it was defned in the answer

Comment: Are you talking about this sequence: 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6? This sequence seems to depend upon a lexicographic ordering of words. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThomasBrowning yes the elements are sorted by their word length with respect to the generating set S, so it depends on S plus the lexicographic ordering of the words.

Comment: Question 1 is just asking whether the number of words of norm $n$ is $n+1$ (i.e. the sequence has one $0$, two $1$'s, three $2$'s,...). This does not depend on the ordering of the sequence and it has absolutely nothing to do with zeta functions. Because of this, it seems rather unlikely that there would be any connection with primes.

Comment: @ThomasBrowning thanks for your insight. That is also what I observed but I have no proof for this. For question 3 I have done some plots, and it seems that there is a relationship. Question 2 is inspired by the   natural numbers whic occur as sequences of the cyclic group.

Comment: I suspect that any relationship between $\pi_{K_4}(n)$ and $\pi(n)$ would arise from the fact that each prime $p$ occurs exactly $p+1$ times in the sequence.

Comment: @ThomasBrowning yes you are right, but the ordering in the sequence is important for question 3. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a word $w=w_0w_1\cdots w_{n-1}$ with each $w_i\in\{0,a,b,c\}$.
Following your notation,
$$\lvert w\rvert=\lvert\zeta(w)\rvert=\left\lvert\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty m^i\cdot(0,w_i)\right\rvert=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert 2^i\cdot(0,w_i)\rvert=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i\lvert w_i\rvert$$
where $\lvert0\rvert=0$, $\lvert a\rvert=1$, $\lvert b\rvert=1$, $\lvert c\rvert=2$.
We now consider the generating function
$$F_n(x)=\sum_wx^{\lvert w\rvert}$$
where the sum is over all words $w=w_0w_1\cdots w_{n-1}$.
Then
\begin{align*}
F_n(x)&=\sum_{w_0}\sum_{w_1}\cdots\sum_{w_{n-1}}x^{|w_0|+2|w_1|+\cdots+2^{n-1}|w_{n-1}|}\\
&=\left(\sum_{w_0}x^{|w_0|}\right)\left(\sum_{w_1}x^{2|w_1|}\right)\cdots\left(\sum_{w_{n-1}}x^{2^{n-1}|w_{n-1}|}\right)\\
&=(1+2x+x^2)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+2x^4+x^8)\cdots(1+2x^{2^{n-1}}+x^{2^n})\\
&=(1+x)^2(1+x^2)^2(1+x^4)^2\cdots(1+x^{2^{n-1}})^2\\
&=(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2^n-1})^2\\
&=1+2x+\cdots+(2^n-1)x^{2^n-2}+2^nx^{2^n-1}+(2^n-1)x^{2^n}+\cdots+x^{2^{n+1}-2}.
\end{align*}

---

What this shows is that among the first $4^n$ terms of the sequence:
\begin{align*}
&0\text{ appears }1\text{ times},\\
&1\text{ appears }2\text{ times},\\
&2\text{ appears }3\text{ times},\\
&\cdots\\
&2^n-2\text{ appears }2^n-1\text{ times},\\
&2^n-1\text{ appears }2^n\text{ times},\\
&2^n\text{ appears }2^n-1\text{ times},\\
&\cdots\\
&2^{n+1}-4\text{ appears }3\text{ times},\\
&2^{n+1}-3\text{ appears }2\text{ times},\\
&2^{n+1}-2\text{ appears }1\text{ times}.\\
\end{align*}
This resolves question 1.
Since this seems to be purely a combinatorics question, I would not expect the second and third questions to have particularly interesting answers.

---

I will remark that
$$\pi_{K_4}(4^n)=\sum_{p\leq2^{n+1}-2}(2^n-\lvert p-2^n+1\rvert)p$$
so you could use some analytic number theory to get asymptotics for $\pi_{K_4}(n)$ if you wanted.

Comment: thanks for your answer. very interesting