# Existence of a multiplication bifunctor for the category of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, finite-groups, monoidal-categories

For $\mathsf{Grp}$ the category of groups, a [bifunctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Bifunctors_and_multifunctors) $M:  \mathsf{Grp} \times \mathsf{Grp}\to  \mathsf{Grp}$ is a *multiplication bifunctor* if:

- $M(C_n,C_m) \simeq C_{nm}$,
- $M(C_1,G) \simeq M(G,C_1) \simeq G$,

for every group $G$ and every $n,m>0$, with $C_n$ the cyclic group of $n$ elements.

**Question**: Is there a multiplication bifunctor for the category of groups?
(or for the subcategory of countable groups, or of finite groups)

*Stronger question*: Is there a multiplication bifunctor providing a [monoidal structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category)?

This post is a multiplicative analogous of [that additive one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351398/34538).

Comment: It's almost the same argument as in my answer in the additive case, as can be seen from Jeremy's answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, I considered this example, but I had the [false belief](https://mathoverflow.net/a/351525/34538) that a subgroup isomorphic to a quotient is a retract...

Comment: We finally get the following funny result: let $F:\mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Grp}$ be a functor, then $F^n(C_1)$ is a retract of $F^{n+1}(C_1)$. For example, if $F(C_1) \simeq C_2$, then $C_2$ is a retract of $F(C_2)$, so in particular, $F(C_2) \not \simeq C_3, C_4$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. $C_1$ is a retract of $C_2$, so $M(C_2,C_1)\simeq C_2$ would have to be a retract of $M(C_2,C_2)\simeq C_4$, which it isn't.