# Classification of the functors on the category of cyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, functoriality, cyclic-groups

Let $\mathsf{Grp}$ be the category of groups and let $\mathsf{Cyc}$ be the subcategory of cyclic groups.
As seen in the posts [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351398/34538) and [there](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351502/34538) (and their answers), a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) $F: \mathsf{Cyc} \to \mathsf{Cyc}$ is a very structured/restrictive notion, we are then lead to wonder whether there exists such a functor which is non-equivalent to the identity or the trivial functor, or if there is a such functor with $F(C_1) \not \simeq C_1$. As pointed out by [Martin Brandenburg](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2841/martin-brandenburg) and [Jeremy Rickard](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22989/jeremy-rickard), $C_1$ is a [retract](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/retract) of $F(C_1)$, so that $F(C_1)$ must be a retract of $F^2(C_1)$, and more generally, $F^n(C_1)$ is a retract of $F^{n+1}(C_1)$, which means that $F^{n+1}(C_1)$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product $F^n(C_1) \ltimes N_n$; now $F^{n+1}(C_1)$ is a cyclic group, so the semidirect product is in fact a direct product and moreover $gcd(|F^n(C_1)|,|N_n|) = 1$.

**Question**: What are the functors on the categroy of cyclic groups?

*Remark*: $Aut(-)$ is not such a functor because $Aut(C_8) \simeq C_2 \times C_2$ (and $Aut^2(C_8) \simeq S_3$).

In his answer, [Neil Strickland](https://mathoverflow.net/users/10366/neil-strickland) provides examples of functors $F$ with $F(C_1) \not \simeq C_1$ and with $F^2(C_1) \not \simeq F(C_1)$, but with $F^3(C_1) \simeq F^2(C_1)$.

**Bonus question**:  Is there a functor $F: \mathsf{Cyc} \to \mathsf{Cyc}$ such that $F^{n+1}(C_1) \not \simeq F^n(C_1)$ for all $n$?

*Remark*: If so, the sequence $(F^n(C_1))_n$ cannot be periodic (for $n$ large enough), because then (as shown above) $F^{n+1}(C_1) \simeq F^{n}(C_1) \times N_n$ with $|N_n|>1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I think that there are too many functors to classify them.

Comment: The first step is to describe the morphisms in $\mathsf{Cyc}$ by generators and relations and thereby to give a description of functors into any category. But it will be quite complicated and not easy to simplify even for simple target categories.

Comment: Another remark: $\mathsf{Cyc}$ has at least two additional structures, for example it is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear (aka preadditive) and symmetric monoidal. It is much easier to classify the functors which preserves one of both of these structures.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Is there a non-constant functor $F$ with $F(C_1) \neq C_1$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Which bifunctor provides a symmetric monoidal structure?

Comment: The first question is answered by Neil below, the second: the tensor product of abelian groups. We have $C_n \otimes C_m = C_{\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)}$ for $n,m \geq 0$.

Answer (score 9):

I'll use additive notation, and I'll assume that you are only considering finite cyclic groups.  Let $\mathbf{Cyc}_p$ be the category of cyclic $p$-groups.  Given $i,j\geq 0$ we can define $Q(p;i,j)\colon\mathbf{Cyc}\to\mathbf{Cyc}_p$ by $Q(p;i,j)(A)=\{a\in p^iA\colon p^ja=0\}$.  We can also define a constant functor $C(p;i)\colon\mathbf{Cyc}\to\mathbf{Cyc}_p$ by $C(p;i)(A)=\mathbb{Z}/p^i$.  Now suppose we have a collection of functors $F_p$, one for each prime $p$, each of the form $Q(p;i,j)$ or $C(p;i)$, and that only finitely many of the functors $F_p$ are constant.  Then the group $F(A)=\prod_pF_p(A)$ is cyclic for all $A$, so we get a functor $F\colon\mathbf{Cyc}\to\mathbf{Cyc}$.  I don't know if that gives all possible functors, but it certainly gives a reasonably rich supply of them.

As a very specific example, the functor $F(A)=(A/2A)\times(\mathbb{Z}/3)$ is non-constant with $F(0)\neq 0$.

UPDATE: Here's a more exotic example.  If $X$ is a based set of size $1$ or $3$, there is a unique group structure for which the basepoint is the identity.  If $A$ is cyclic of order $1$ or $7$ then we can impose an equivalence relation with $a\sim a^2\sim a^4$ for all $a$, and then $A/\sim$ has size $1$ or $3$ with basepoint $0$ and so has a group structure.  This construction gives a functor on the category of groups of order $1$ or $7$, and we can compose with $A\mapsto A/7$ to get a functor $\mathbf{Cyc}\to\mathbf{Cyc}_3$.  I am sure that there are many variations on this theme.

Comment: From the other questions I assume that $C_0 = \mathbb{Z}$ belongs to $\mathsf{Cyc}$.

Comment: Is there a functor $F$ with $F^2(C_1) \neq F(C_1)$?

Comment: If $G$ is the functor in my update, and $FA=\mathbb{Z}/7\times GA$ then $F0=\mathbb{Z}/7$ and $F^20=\mathbb{Z}/21$.